# Making button enable and disabled for a certain time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new in Android Studio. I want to make a chat apps.
So, I want to make a delay after he/she send a message.
For an example, I write input "Hello", if I send again, it will display Toast to show time, 5 seconds, 4 seconds until finish. Then I will able to send the message again.

And, if I press the button within that time, it will show how many seconds to able to send the message.

I made one, but not run as expected.

```
private void buttonFabSend() {
        floatingActionButtonSendText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new CountDownTimer( 5000, 1000){
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),millisUntilFinished/1000 +"seconds",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                        floatingActionButtonSendText.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        editTextInput = findViewById(R.id.editTextChat);
                        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editTextInput.getText().toString())) {
                            editTextInput.setError("Enter your message");
                            editTextInput.requestFocus();
                            return;
                        }
                        floatingActionButtonSendText.setEnabled(true);
                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chat").push().setValue(new chatMessage(editTextInput.getText().toString(), FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName(), String.valueOf(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl())));
                        editTextInput.setText("");
                    }
                }.start();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncomment your code Of Sending message

```
    int _count = 5;//5 seconds
    private boolean canSendMessage = true;
    private Runnable countDown = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (_count > 0) {
                _count--;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);//1 second
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            _count = 5;//again set to 5 seconds
            canSendMessage = true;//enable send

        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_test);

        final Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (canSendMessage) {
                    //
//                    editTextInput = findViewById(R.id.editTextChat);
//                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editTextInput.getText().toString())) {
//                        editTextInput.setError("Enter your message");
//                        editTextInput.requestFocus();
//                        return;
//                    }
//                    floatingActionButtonSendText.setEnabled(true);
//                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chat").push().setValue(new chatMessage(editTextInput.getText().toString(), FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName(), String.valueOf(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl())));
//                    editTextInput.setText("");
                    canSendMessage = false;
                    Thread t = new Thread(countDown);
                    t.start();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(UploadTest.this, "You can send After " + _count + " Seconds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use some logic like this:

```
private long delay = 4000;

void onViewClick(View view) {
    view.setEnabled(false);
    view.postDelayed(() -> {
        view.setEnabled(true);
    }, delay);
}
```

Better you may want to check if after the delay the view is still attached to window or not

```
private long delay = 4000;
void onViewClick(View view) {
    view.setEnabled(false);
    view.postDelayed(() -> {
        if (ViewCompat.isAttachedToWindow(view) {
            view.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }, delay);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, everytime new countdown timer will initialize, so it will not work proper, what you need to do is only start countdown timer once until its finish. please try below code

```
boolean isRunning = false;
long currentMillisUntilFinished = 0;
```

and replace **floatingActionButtonSendText** `click` event with below code

```
floatingActionButtonSendText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (isRunning) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "seconds remaining: " + currentMillisUntilFinished / 1000, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                currentMillisUntilFinished = millisUntilFinished;
                isRunning = true;

            }

            public void onFinish() {
                isRunning = false;
                editTextInput = findViewById(R.id.editTextChat);
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editTextInput.getText().toString())) {
                    editTextInput.setError("Enter your message");
                    editTextInput.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chat").push().setValue(new chatMessage(editTextInput.getText().toString(), FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName(), String.valueOf(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl())));
                editTextInput.setText("");
            }

        }.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: @Zuhrain, i have updated my answer, just replace your floatingActionButtonSendText `click` event code with mine.